# Upgrading 1.9.3 with latest stables - Internal server error 500

Tags: upgrade, server-setup, magento1.9.3

The upgrade went ahead with no errors however I now have internal server errors anywhere beyond home page including the admin area.
I have checked the server error log and it appears to be related to file.php (see below).  Just wondering if there is a quick fix.  I set all files to 644 and folders to 755 as suggested in another post.

Server error log one of the line entries which just repeats on different date/time stamps:

```
2017-01-29T17:13:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): is_readable() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given/homepages/3/d541438922/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/Dogcrafts_Retail_Shop/lib/Varien/Io/File.php
2017-01-29T17:13:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): is_readable() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given/homepages/3/d541438922/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Magento/Dogcrafts_Retail_Shop/lib/Varien/Io/File.php
2017-01-29T17:14:16+00:00
```

and so on and on !

Comment: Did the permissions change solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry no the permissions didn't fix the problem

Comment: Bump! I still have a problem can anyone please help ?

Comment: I am assuming you have this is a test environment? Can you try setting all files to 777 to see if that solves the issue?  I am also assuming you can removed all the cache files in var/cache

Comment: thank you for your reply..... deleted cache files and reset files to 777 and still not working.  The home page appears but any link after that still gives the internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up re-installing 1.9.3 pre-update. website working just fine again.  No solution to problem found other than a re-install.